# how to do scp in linux

Tags: linux, connection, scp

I am getting following error while doing scp, what could be the reason?

```
[~/workspace/xr-dev/call-home/core/src] /usr/bin/scp myfile.c host2:/scratch/shirohua/


shirohua@host2's password:
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
[-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
[[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
lost connection
[~/workspace/xr-dev/call-home/core/src]
```

Comment: Try `scp -v` and read the log. The `usage` error message suggests to me that someone has messed up with the `sshd` configuration on the server.

Comment: Looks like dropbear scp. Something is likely wrong with the remote host. You should provide some details about that host.

Comment: when I do verbose mode , I get following output

Answer (score 0):

Copy a local file to a remote host:

```
   scp {{path/to/local_file}} {{remote_host}}:{{path/to/remote_file}}
```

try to provide full path to your local file

Additionally, make sure /scratch/shirohua/ exists